# How to work around slow joining queries in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an MVC 4 project that is using Code First with Entity Framework 6 (backed by SQL Server 2008).  I'm trying to optimize a particularly nasty query that looks something like:

```
var tops = Context.Top
    .Include(t => 
        t.Foo
            .Select(f => f.FooChild1
                .Select(c => c.Baz)))
    .Include(t =>
        t.Foo
            .Select(f => f.FooChild3))
    .Include(t =>
        t.Foo
            .Select(f => f.FooChild2))
    .Include(t =>
        t.Foo
            .Select(f => f.FooChild1
                .Select(c => c.Bar)))
    .Where(t => t.Foo.Count > 0)
    .ToList();
```

Where the relationships look like:

```
Top  
    1 ----> 0..N  Foo
        1 ----> 0..N  FooChild1
            1 ----> 0..N Bar
            1 ----> 0..N Baz
        1 ----> 0..N FooChild2
        0..N ----> 1 FooChild3
```

As you can see, the query does a lot of eager loading, so the resulting query has a lot of joins.  Lazy loading has proved much too slow for what I'm doing with the resulting data.

The generated query for this takes about 2 seconds to execute on my SQL Server, but a hand written query that obtains the data I need only takes about 91 ms.  Is there anything I can do to improve this?

**What I have tried**

I tried pre-loading by calling `Load()` on all of the other tables that I need and getting rid of all the `Include`'s.  I'm not sure why (maybe this trick does not work with `DbContext`), but it had no effect.  Navigation properties were lazy loaded.

**What I am considering**

1. One option that occurs to me would be to hand write a SQL view that queries the data I need, and map an entity to it in Code First.  Not sure how to do that exactly, but I hope that by doing that I could avoid the bad performance in the generated query.
2. Modifying the design of my database so the information I need is cached in the `Top` table.  I don't like the duplication of data in this option, but at least I wouldn't have to traverse so many navigation properties.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use precompiled query to improve performance in your case.
Something like (example from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb896297.aspx) cause I don't know your types):

```
static readonly Func<AdventureWorksEntities, Decimal, IQueryable<SalesOrderHeader>> s_compiledQuery2 = 
    CompiledQuery.Compile<AdventureWorksEntities, Decimal, IQueryable<SalesOrderHeader>>(
            (ctx, total) => from order in ctx.SalesOrderHeaders
                            where order.TotalDue >= total
                            select order);

static void CompiledQuery2()
{            
    using (AdventureWorksEntities context = new AdventureWorksEntities())
    {
        Decimal totalDue = 200.00M;

        IQueryable<SalesOrderHeader> orders = s_compiledQuery2.Invoke(context, totalDue);

        foreach (SalesOrderHeader order in orders)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}  Order date: {1} Total due: {2}",
                order.SalesOrderID,
                order.OrderDate,
                order.TotalDue);
        }
    }            
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not sure compiled queries would help me... perhaps you can elaborate?  My understanding is that compiled queries are helpful if you are repeatedly making the same query.  My problem is in how inefficient the generated query is (20x slower than a hand created one), and I have a feeling that the on-the-fly query compilation time is negligible compared to the 2 seconds it takes for my query to execute on the SQL Server.

Comment: did you profile it? And did you compare ef generated queries with your hand made query? if you show them in compare I could help you more precisely.